# How to add a navigation sidebar and a footer to an AngularJS template without ng-include.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to angular development. I have been using a few paid angular admin themes. In all of them, developers have only added `ng-view` and `ng-class` attribute to `index.html`. I just want to know how to add a sidebar navigation and a footer to every page without using any `ng-include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use `ng-include`, you can put your HTML directly in the `index.html`. That is called a [*layout template*](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07), which is the view that contains the common elements along your application.

In summary, everything in `index.html` outside the `ng-view` element is going to appear in every page (as long as you use any module such as `angular-route` for routing within the same original HTML document (e.g. `index.html`)).

I would recommend you to follow the official [AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) if you are new to this framework. Also, [*ng-book* by Ari Lerner](https://www.ng-book.com/) is a must-read on this topic.

Comment: thank you for reply. didn find anywhere the exact solution but some plugins  helped me.

Comment: @rohanpadwalkar, share your workaround, please. I think I didn't understand your question at first.

Comment: you answer worked. ng-route helped me to achieve required.